# Enabling Z value in Point feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates

I have point features.

How do I add X,Y,Z coordinate to the attribute table?

Answer (score 2):

Use tool [Add Geomtry Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm):

> Adds new attribute fields to the input features representing the
>   spatial or geometric characteristics and location of each feature,
>   such as length or area and x-, y-, z-, and m-coordinates.

With Geometry Property POINT_X_Y_Z_M:

[image]